# Is it possible to get a mortgage in the UK with a Tier2 ICT Visa

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage, visa

I currently live in the UK under a Tier 2 ICT visa and have been contemplating the idea of buying a house. Would I be able to get a mortgage with this kind of visa?